# In MySQL how to write SQL from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Every time a user plays a game I insert a new row into table game_log.

```
create table game_log (
  userId int, 
  gameId int
);

insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (1, 100);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (1, 101);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (2, 100);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (2, 101);    
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (2, 102);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (3, 100);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (3, 101);
insert into game_log (userId, gameId) values (3, 102);
```

I want to create a report of the distribution of users by total games played.  That is to say how many people played 1 game, 2 games, 3 games, etc.

```
select Nbr, count(*)
  (select count(*) as 'Nbr', UserId
  from game_log
  group by UserId
  ) as tbl
group by Nbr;
```

I would expect to get a report like this:

```
Results:
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
```

In other words, there is 1 person that played 2 games.  There are 2 people that played 3 games.

But instead I get a sql syntax error, any idea why?

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select count(*) as 'Nbr', UserId
  from game_log
  group by UserId
  ) as tbl
g' at line 2
```

Comment: How can we have any idea if we don't know what error occurs?

Comment: sounds like you want to use joins for this

Comment: Your expected results don't make sense to me, each `userID` plays 3 games...

Comment: Goat CO, if you look at the insert statements, note that userId 1 only played 2 games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just missing `FROM`:

```
SELECT Nbr, count(*)
FROM (SELECT count(*) as 'Nbr', UserId
      FROM game_log
      GROUP BY UserId
      ) as tbl
GROUP BY Nbr;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a3a/3/0)